# Lua integrating event loop

Tags: c++, lua

I am new to Lua, and looking for ways to integrate it into my app with some sort of event loop. I've found [a textbook example](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html), and [a dedicated library](https://github.com/brimworks/lua-ev) regarding this.

What I fail to see is that once I run the event loop function, since it runs indefinitely without returning, how can I invoke other Lua functions in the same context from C/C++, meaning to "inject" a function call into the Lua event loop? What's the preferred way of doing this today?

The solution needs to be portable (OS X, Windows)

Comment: Can you show the code, or at least an example of what you're doing with it?

Comment: No, there is no code yet, I am trying to figure out the way to do this.

Comment: "some sort of event loop" is way too broad.  What's the nature of your app? Who do you want to own the main loop? What work do you want to be done in the Lua portion of the loop?

Comment: Just imagine a situation that I invoke a Lua function which starts downloading some files from the web, and yields. Meanwhile, due to some user action detected in the c/c++ code, I would like to invoke some other lua action, which perhaps downloads just another file, but the lua event loop is still working on the previous file. How could I inject anything into the still running event loop? Or I could implement an event loop in native code, but then how would it know that there is something to resume?

Comment: @ZsoltSzatmari, one of the ways to do this is creating 2 threads and using some thread-safe message queue. Basically, one thread is going to fill message queue with tasks/files/whatever and on the other thread You'll have LuaVM running Your event loop and checking/popping tasks/files/whatever from the message queue.

Comment: Kamiccolo: Yeah, that makes sense!